# Creating Circular Dependency Error on Field Injection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

Tech Stack: Java-11, Spring, SpringBoot

I am trying to re-create a scenario, where **Field Injection** in Spring would cause **Circular Dependency Error**

- Class A is injected to Class B
- Class B is injected to Class A
- At Spring Run time, I was expecting the Circular Injection Error to come but it didnt
- In class CallingService, I am trying to call class A's method which refers to class B's method. But that also didnt create the Circular Dependency Error.

Class A

```
@Service
@Data
public class A {

    @Autowired B b;

    String str = "B";

    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println(b.str); // referring to B's instance
    }
}
```

Class B

```
@Service
@Data
public class B {

    @Autowired A a;

    String str = "B";

    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println(a.str); // referring to A's instance
    }
}
```

Class CallingService <---- (trying to create Circular Dependency Error in this class)

```
@Service
@Data
public class CallingService {

    @Autowired A a;

    public void methodCalled() {
        System.out.println(a.str); // This printed successfully as "A"
    }
}
```

My Queries:

1. Circular Dependency is expected at `run-time` or while `reference-time`(when code is referred while running) in **Field Injection** [This is clear now. It will come at SPRING's]
2. What changes do I do to my code to create Circular Dependency Error here using *Field Injection*
3. I am actually insisting for using Field Type Injection instead of Constructor Type Injection at my office project, as the prior is quick and eliminates verbose code.

   - Went through few blogs which were recommending `Constructor-Dependency` but found most of the points lame. Only concerning one was of `Circular Dependency Error`. So trying to recreate the same as a POC.

Comment: a side note "I am actually insisting for using Field Type Injection instead of Constructor Type Injection" - this will bite you, as it did everyone else that thought so.

Comment: iirc you can achieve this with `@PostConstruct` - try to use your dependencies there

Comment: @Eugene Unable to understand how ! Most examples I found over net were theoretical instead of practical examples

Comment: @Eugene But my code ran well. No Errors. Print was successful.

Comment: lots and lots of these issues where fixed in spring-4. I do not have time now to find where I have re-prodcuded this a while ago, but may be I will later.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks in anticipation. I have seen you reverting back before also :)

Answer (score 0):

Asking your questions:

1. Circular dependency error is avoided with Setter or Field injection. The reason being that Spring creates the beans, but the dependencies are not injected until they are needed. In Constructor injection it will ever be a runtime error, never compile time.
2. Use Constructor injection. But you only get the error on runtime.
3. Constructor injection is way more unit test friendly than Setter or Field injection, so I also recommend you using Constructor injection.

Comment: Constructor injection is way more unit test friendly : This some how sounds Old School, as with the kind of libraries available like `Jupiter` etc, such issues never arise . Further would like to hear your thoughts too !

Comment: You are talking about JUnit Jupiter I guess. To be honest I am not aware of how JUnit Jupiter work around Field Injection when you want to mock the dependencies. Nevertheless, Constructor injection has the advantage that you don't need to annotate all dependencies with @Autowired as you do with Setter or Field Injection (verbose). Additionally, I don't mind the circular dependency error that one might get with Constructor injection since it usually means bad design. Finally, we moved to Kotlin 3 years ago and thus we don't feel the pain of "verbose code" that you might be feeling with Java.